# best practices for finding words from a dictionary given the content on a webpage javascript

Tags: javascript, search, dictionary

You know how those pop up advertisements work? the ones that are super annoying when you hover over them.  I want to create something similar.

What I want to do is given specific per-determined words with a given "definition" associated with those words, like a key value pair,  search my web page for those words then make those words if clicked on pop up a little tooltip giving that words definition, the value.

Now I can kinda piece this together but I want to do it the most efficient way with caching the dictionary and caching as much as possible. so I don't have to create two arrays every time the page loads then check if the words on the page match anything in the dictionary and if so make a tooltip or little pop up.

Can anyone give me any ideas or even code hints/links to help me get the best results/load times so It doesn't take forever every time the web page loads.

I haven't started making any of it yet, so I can go any route, I just want it to be fast.

Comment: why do you want that the visitors of your website get annoyed and leave your page? Just add mouseover event on the words you want. If a user open your page find the word with a server-side language and look them up with your server-side language too and print them in any javascript object.

Comment: hey micha, i don't want people to get annoyed and leave my page. For one you have to click on it instead of hover (like i mentioned in post) and two it wont be selling you anything, it'll be providing value to their experience o the site.  So it is similar implementation but different result and functionality.  Can you elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your text container element and `split(' ')` it's content by words. Iterate over this array of words and wrap those of the words that are in the dictionary with a `span` or some other element. Then, `join(' ')` the array back and replace the container's `innerHTML` with it.

Next, add a listener to the container with a handler that will react only if `e.target` is a `span`.

```
container.addEventListenter('click', function (e) {
    if ('SPAN' === e.target.tagName) {
        lookUpWord(e.target)
    }
}, false)
```

The function `lookUpWord` will analyze the `span`'s text and draw the looked up definition.

As for the format of the dictionary, it'd better be a simple JSON object, like this one:

```
var dictionary = {
    "astrolabe": "An astronomical and navigational instrument for gauging the altitude of the Sun and stars.",
    "logarithm": "For a number x, the power to which a given base number must be raised in order to obtain x.",
    "Darth Vader": "Lover, warrior, Dark Lord of the Sith."
}
```

A lookup in such an object would be as trivial as:

```
 var word = 'Darth Vader'
 var definition = dictionary[word]
```

To check if a word is in the dictionary:

```
if (word in dictionary) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, would you consider this an expensive operation? Would you store the dictionary in xml and find the words key to get it's value?

Comment: thanks ALot! sounds like the best route to go for now. I'll start piecing this together later tonight.

Comment: @Jared, no problem! More specific questions are welcome.

Comment: Hey I just ran into a sorta blockage and was wondering if you had any more input.  What if the dictionary had a string key that was two words. like "Darth Vader" : "Bad Ass Father" .   The above example wouldn't work.  However Some of the things in my dictionary are gonna be like this.  Do I need to go about this another way then? Thanks!

Comment: An object key can be any string. With valid identifiers you can access properties via both dot and bracket notaions (`dictionary.logarithm` or `dictionary['logarithm']`), but with other arbitrary strings or variables – only via brackets (`dictionary['Darth Vader']`). Please, ask such things in separate questions.

Comment: hey thanks katspaugh that part makes sense.  I posted a new question here thanks again.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413651/find-multiple-key-words