# find multiple key words within a dictionary Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, dictionary

I am trying to perform a dictionary look up on some content and my approach so far I can only look up single words because I am using the split(' ') method splitting on just the space. I just ran into a sorta blockage and was wondering if guys you had any solid input.  like what if I have keys in my dictionary that are of two words. Like below

```
var  dictionary = { "Darth Vader" : "Bad Ass Father", "Luke": "Son of the Bad Ass",
"Skywalker" : "Last name of some Jedi Knights", "Luke SkyWalker" : "Son of the Bad Ass"}
```

this is the code I got so far and it works for single words obviously but not muliplte key words.  getElementsByClassName is a function to return an array of all classes found.

```
var body = '<div class="activity-inner"> This is a test glossary body paragraph to test glossary highlight of the Star Wars vocabulary. like Luke Skywalker and Darth Vader, Luke and Skywalker. </div> <div class="activity-inner">Hello glossary again here Luke Skywalker Darth Vader</div>';
document.write( body);
var matches = getElementsByClassName("activity-inner");
for (int i = 0; i < matches.length; i++;) {
var content = matches[i].innerHTML;
document.write(content);
var  words = content.split(' ');



for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
var temp = words[j].replace(/[^\w\s]|_/g, "")
     .replace(/\s+/g, " ").toLowerCase();
 if (temp in dictionary) {
words[j] = "<span class='highlight' style='color:green;'>"+words[j]+"</span>";
}
document.write(words[j] +"<br />");



}
body = words.join(' ');
document.write( "<br /> <br />" + body);
}
```

The above example wouldn't work. However Some of the things in my dictionary are gonna be like this. How should I go about this and maybe avoid case as well if at all possible? Thanks!

Comment: `for (var match in matches)` shouldn't be used to iterate over arrays. Besides that, jQuery might make your job easier.

Comment: oh okay thanks you.  Ill change that to a sequential counter loop.

Comment: In the second loop `word` is the index, not the indexed element. The indexed element would be `words[word]` (you get it right on the next line).

Comment: thanks katspaugh, I changed all my for loops to use a sequential counter loop but i did not update this code.  But you are correct however thanks!

Comment: And don't use `document.write`. Use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) instead.

Comment: Oh okay thanks.  I will not be using that when the concept is complete. for now I just have a test html page and those are my bad way of printing them to the screen just for testing purposes.

Comment: I have reverted your changes, since the *new question* has different requirements, causing the accepted answer to be incorrect. You should create a new question for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a RegEx, consisting of all keys of the dictionary (to prevent a replacement from being replaced again). Then, use `String.replace(pattern, replace_function)` as shown below.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7DqF/**

```
// Example
var dictionary = { "Darth Vader" : "Bad Ass Father", "Luke": "Son of the Bad Ass",
"Skywalker" : "Last name of some Jedi Knights", "Luke SkyWalker" : "Son of the Bad Ass"}
    content = "....";

var pattern = [],
    key;
for (key in dictionary) {
    // Sanitize the key, and push it in the list
    pattern.push(key.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1'));
}
pattern = "(?:" + pattern.join(")|(?:") + ")"; //Create pattern
pattern = new RegExp(pattern, "g");

// Walk through the string, and replace every occurrence of the matched tokens
content = content.replace(pattern, function(full_match){
    return dictionary[full_match];
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks!  I just have one question.  How would I keep the word there and then just append the definition? like Luke Son of the Bad Ass.

Comment: Replace `return dictionary[full_match];` with `return full_match + dictionary[full_match];`. If you want a space between, replace the `+` with `+ " " +`.

Comment: marked as answer. Thanks!  also that demo link was extremely helpful.

Comment: Hey ROb W.  I am really thankful for your help. I have a two questions though about your implementation.  The first is: I believe this matches words that are not whole. Like if short is in my dictionary it matches the word shortly. How would I stop this?  And the second not so important but would be nice is: How would I make it so it only matches once per content? So short doesn't get defined twice.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: weird it seems to work in the demo link above, but not in my implementation which is pretty much the exact same thing.  I refreshed my browser and looked inside the javascript file and it is showing the change with the \\b's  added but still matches shortly.  my website is private so I can not provide a link, any ideas? I added my function above in an edit

Comment: I made an accessible page that you could check out. here is a link http://www.howtousethinkorswim.com/testHighlightGlossary.php Thanks again.

Comment: @Jared Can you create a new question? To meet both requirements, I have to create a different approach. You can describe it as a "follow-up" question, eg. `"This is a follow-up question to <link>. I had to add two additional requirements:......"`

Comment: @Jared My answer is ready, you have to post your question now. Also, can you delete some irrelevant comments at this chain? That would make it easier to read for others ;) Btw, to not match shortly, simple add \\b around the parens: `pattern = "\\b(?:" + pattern.join(")\\b|\\b(?:") + ")\\b"; //Create pattern`.

Comment: Hey ROb W thanks for getting back to me.  I created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672709/regex-word-boundary-not-working-with-javascript-content