# Find and replace by a dictionary, using keys only once

Tags: javascript, regex, search, dictionary, replace

*This is a follow-up of [Find multiple keywords within a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413651/find-multiple-key-words-within-a-dictionary-javascript).*

My questions are...

1. The first is: I believe this matches words that are not whole. Like if short is in my dictionary it matches the word shortly. How would I stop this?
2. And the second not so important but would be nice is: How would I make it so it only matches once per content? So short doesn't get defined twice within the same content area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have implemented the following additional requirements:

- Do not match `shortly` when looking for `short` (because `shortly` is a different word)
- Use keys in the dictionary only once.
  Example input: key=`foo`, replacement=`bar`, content=`foo foo`.
  Output: `bar foo` (only the first `foo` is replaced).

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bhGE3/3/**

Usage:

1. Define a `dictionary`. Each key will be used only once.
2. Define `content`. A new string will be created, based on this string.
3. *Optionally*, define a `replacehandler` function. This function is called at each match. The return value will be used to replace the matched phrase.
   The default `replacehandler` will return the dictionary's matching phrase. The function should take two arguments: `key` and `dictionary`.
4. Call `replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content, replacehandler)`
5. Process the output, eg. show `content` to the user.

#### Code:

```
var dictionary = {
    "history": "war . ",
    "no": "in a",
    "nothing": "",
    "oops": "",
    "time": "while",
    "there": "We",
    "upon": "in",
    "was": "get involved"
};
var content = "Once upon a time... There was no history. Nothing. Oops";
content = replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content, function(key, dictionary){
    return '_' + dictionary[key] + '_';
});
alert(content);
// End of implementation

/*
* @name        replaceOnceUsingDictionary
* @author      Rob W http://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w
* @description Replaces phrases in a string, based on keys in a given dictionary.
*               Each key is used only once, and the replacements are case-insensitive
* @param       Object dictionary  {key: phrase, ...}
* @param       String content
* @param       Function replacehandler
* @returns     Modified string
*/
function replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content, replacehandler) {
    if (typeof replacehandler != "function") {
        // Default replacehandler function.
        replacehandler = function(key, dictionary){
            return dictionary[key];
        }
    }
    
    var patterns = [], // \b is used to mark boundaries "foo" doesn't match food
        patternHash = {},
        oldkey, key, index = 0,
        output = [];
    for (key in dictionary) {
        // Case-insensitivity:
        key = (oldkey = key).toLowerCase();
        dictionary[key] = dictionary[oldkey];
        
        // Sanitize the key, and push it in the list
        patterns.push('\\b(?:' + key.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1') + ')\\b');
        
        // Add entry to hash variable, for an optimized backtracking at the next loop
        patternHash[key] = index++;
    }
    var pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi'),
        lastIndex = 0;

    // We should actually test using !== null, but for foolproofness,
    //  we also reject empty strings
    while (key = pattern.exec(content)) {
        // Case-insensitivity
        key = key[0].toLowerCase();

        // Add to output buffer
        output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, pattern.lastIndex - key.length));
        // The next line is the actual replacement method
        output.push(replacehandler(key, dictionary));

        // Update lastIndex variable
        lastIndex = pattern.lastIndex;

        // Don't match again by removing the matched word, create new pattern
        patterns[patternHash[key]] = '^';
        pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi');

        // IMPORTANT: Update lastIndex property. Otherwise, enjoy an infinite loop
        pattern.lastIndex = lastIndex;
    }
    output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, content.length));
    return output.join('');
}
```

Comment: Hey Rob W. Thanks so much to take the time to code this up.  I hope to some day get to a level of programming confidence, where I can too can do the same for others.  I have one quick thing that I think i could fix but thought I would just ask.  The key gets returned completely lowercase so if the original content was Short then it gets returned as short. Like I said i could probably fix it by getting rid of the two .toLowerCase() and adding it to the dictionary[key.toLowerCase()] but thought i would ask first. Thanks.

Comment: The dictionary's keys have to be either lower, or uppercase if you want to support a case-insensitive match. The reason is that JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. `dictionary.Foo` is not equal to `dictionary.foo`. In the current application, only the case of the new (replaced) phrase is relevant. The key's case can only be preserved if the whole dictionary is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes my dictionary is gonna be case sensitive.  Its all gonna be lower case.

Comment: Hey @rob-w it looks like the above solution no longer works for chrome firefox and IE are good though.  The highlight does not get rendered properly and I am having a hard time getting it to work.  Any thoughts? I know google just came out with a new update. Check the demo site. It is not working on chrome, Thanks!

Comment: @Jared I have updated the code. Chrome enforces strict rules regarding function declarations vs expressions. It's now working ;)

Comment: oh wow thank you.  I see you changed and made replacehandler a var now and not a function and it worked for me.

Comment: At the top of the function, I replaced the function **declaration** `function replacehandler(key, dictionary){` with the function **expression** `var replacehandler = function(key, dictionary){`. The first one will always be defined (Chrome), whilst the second one will only be defined if the condition (at the if-block) is met.

Comment: Hey @rob-w Thanks again that fixed it on Chrome and it works in firefox but it seems now after the new fix IE8 works however it states the definition twice once in my pop up and then again after the defined word.  I thought you may have an idea as to why.  Thanks!

Comment: IE is right, I have removed `var` (because the variable has already been declared via the formal parameters). `function replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content,`  **`replacehandler`** `)`.

Comment: Hey Rob, once again I appreciate your help.  It seems on my test page outside my site I am can not duplicate this error but within my site even with the var fix it is still happening. I looked through the code and sure enough it putting the code in twice. once within the link class highlight and once outside the link.  I would give you a link but its a private website.

Comment: Have you ensured that the script is not *cached*, after the update? What error do you get, if any? If the error still persists, can you copy-paste the (relevant) generated HTML to a place such as http://pastebin.com/? An expiration period of one day is sufficient.