# Replace Function words for 1 text fields but, not working on multiple fields

Tags: javascript

I have a replace function which matches a string or single word with the defined input values and outputs a specified word against it.

The way I have designed the function only allows it to work with a single input and single output textarea on a page and I cannot apply multiple functions so the input from 1 input field are processed by different functions and showed on different output textarea fields.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input_1" class="text-area-main input_mainn" type="text" placeholder="Input Goes Here" oninput="funcinput1()"> //input

<textarea id="output_1" class="text-area-main"></textarea> //output 1
<textarea id="output_2" class="text-area-main"></textarea> //output
```

JS:

```
function funcinput1() {
    let translator = {
        "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog": "a fast brown fox jumps ovew a wazy good boy",
        "Hello there":"Ello There",
        "n":"\ud83d\udc68\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c\udffd"
    };
    
    var input = document.querySelector("#input_1");
    var output = document.querySelector("#output_1");

    input.addEventListener("input", () => {
        let text = input.value;
        let translated = translator[text];
        if (!translated) {
            let words = input.value.split(" ");
            translated = words.map(word => translator[word] || word).join(" ");
        }
        output.value = translated;
    });
  };
```

I know I am doing it wrong by applying the function on input field instead of doing it on the output textarea but, I cannot figure out how to make the whole scenario work.

IN short, the input would be from single input field but, there can be multiple output text areas and each will do the processing according to the function attached to it.

Example:

Input is: "Hello there"

Output 1 can be: "Ello There"

Output 2 can be: "Hey There"

This can go upto 10 or 20 fields from each input and 20 different functions but, on same page.

I am still learning and cannot figure out how to do it in the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a dictionary of translations for each output text area.

And on input, you can reuse the function to translate based on a key which is `id` of output area as well key in dictionary.

Consider below example, which can be extended easily for `n` number of output areas -

```js
const translator = {
  "output_1": {
    "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog": "a fast brown fox jumps ovew a wazy good boy",
    "Hello there": "Ello There",
    "n": "\ud83d\udc68\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c\udffd"
  },
  "output_2": {
    "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog": "new fox",
    "Hello there": "Hey There",
    "n": "no"
  }
};

document.querySelector("#input_1").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  for (const output of Object.keys(translator)) {
    document.querySelector(`#${output}`).value = translate(e.target, output);
  }
});

function translate(input, outputSelector) {
  const text = input.value;
  let translated = translator[outputSelector][text];
  if (!translated) {
    const words = input.value.split(" ");
    translated = words.map(word => translator[word] || word).join(" ");
  }
  return translated;
}
```

```html
<input id="input_1" class="text-area-main input_mainn" type="text" placeholder="Input Goes Here">

<textarea id="output_1" class="text-area-main"></textarea>
<textarea id="output_2" class="text-area-main"></textarea>
```

If you wish to do anything different for each output area other than using the dictionary, add an `if` condition or better call a function based on the key (create a a dictionary of custom functions to be applied).

---

### EDIT 1:

Using solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672709/find-and-replace-by-a-dictionary-using-keys-only-once) -

```js
const translator = {
  "output_1": {
    "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog": "a fast brown fox jumps ovew a wazy good boy",
    "Hello there": "Ello There",
    "n": "\ud83d\udc68\u200d\ud83e\udd1d\u200d\ud83d\udc68\ud83c\udffd"
  },
  "output_2": {
    "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog": "new fox",
    "Hello there": "Hey There",
    "n": "no"
  }
};

document.querySelector("#input_1").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  for (const output of Object.keys(translator)) {
    document.querySelector(`#${output}`).value = translate(e.target, output);
  }
});

function translate(input, outputSelector) {
  const text = input.value;
  const currentTranslator = translator[outputSelector];
  const translated = replaceOnceUsingDictionary(currentTranslator, text, function(key, dictionary) {
    return dictionary[key];
  });
  return translated;
}

/*
 * @description Replaces phrases in a string, based on keys in a given dictionary.
 *               Each key is used only once, and the replacements are case-insensitive
 * @param       Object dictionary  {key: phrase, ...}
 * @param       String content
 * @param       Function replacehandler
 * @returns     Modified string
 */
function replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content, replacehandler) {
  if (typeof replacehandler != "function") {
    // Default replacehandler function.
    replacehandler = function(key, dictionary) {
      return dictionary[key];
    }
  }

  var patterns = [], // \b is used to mark boundaries "foo" doesn't match food
    patternHash = {},
    oldkey, key, index = 0,
    output = [];
  for (key in dictionary) {
    // Case-insensitivity:
    key = (oldkey = key).toLowerCase();
    dictionary[key] = dictionary[oldkey];

    // Sanitize the key, and push it in the list
    patterns.push('\\b(?:' + key.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1') + ')\\b');

    // Add entry to hash variable, for an optimized backtracking at the next loop
    patternHash[key] = index++;
  }
  var pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi'),
    lastIndex = 0;

  // We should actually test using !== null, but for foolproofness,
  //  we also reject empty strings
  while (key = pattern.exec(content)) {
    // Case-insensitivity
    key = key[0].toLowerCase();

    // Add to output buffer
    output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, pattern.lastIndex - key.length));
    // The next line is the actual replacement method
    output.push(replacehandler(key, dictionary));

    // Update lastIndex variable
    lastIndex = pattern.lastIndex;

    // Don't match again by removing the matched word, create new pattern
    patterns[patternHash[key]] = '^';
    pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi');

    // IMPORTANT: Update lastIndex property. Otherwise, enjoy an infinite loop
    pattern.lastIndex = lastIndex;
  }
  output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, content.length));
  return output.join('');
}
```

```html
<input id="input_1" class="text-area-main input_mainn" type="text" placeholder="Input Goes Here">

<textarea id="output_1" class="text-area-main"></textarea> 
<textarea id="output_2" class="text-area-main"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hey Nikhil, Thanks for the assistance and suggesting a solution. This works just fine but, if you could help me solve another bug in the code, that would be awesome. 

The translator works just fine for full sentences and words but, if a full sentence is entered in which several word phrases will be translated, the translator does not work if there are any words preceding or after the defined values. 

Example:

"a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog" works fine but if I enter "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog and walks like a sheep", it won't translate the defined phrase.

Comment: @AhmadWahid, What you require is bit more complex, since you have to search through whole dictionary to find matches to the words or parts of word. This becomes more complex, when there are matches with 2 keys in dictionary. It would be easier to implement if you specify rules for matching the keys. I was thinking about how to implement it, but luckily I found a similar solution. Although, this solution replaces keys only once, it works for words with spaces. Maybe check it on your end if it does what you want?

Comment: Nikhil, this code with some modifications seems to be working for me. Thanks a lot for that! You rock :)